# I don't succeed while i'm compiling a simple .tex with .bib

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, texlive

I have just two simple files one called "test.tex" and other called "references.bib" they are in the same directory. When I first use the command:
pdflatex test.tex i receive this message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.6-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2014/dev)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `greenwade93' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.
```

then a I use the command bibtex test.aux and I receive this message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014/dev)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There was 1 error message)
```

I have already tried a lot of times continue the compilatio (more two times of pdflatex command) but it doesn't works.

My both codes are simple, as you can see:
test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\centerline{\sc \large A Simple Sample \LaTeX\ File}
\vspace{.5pc}
\centerline{\sc Stupid Stuff I Wish Someone Had Told Me Four Years Ago}
\centerline{\it (Read the .tex file along with this or it won't
            make much sense)}
\vspace{2pc}

Test text\cite{greenwade93}

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
```

I'm using a Fedora version 20, I've installed by yum the texlive and the latexmk, I've been also trying to use Atom Text Editor with the package latex-plus package, but since I've realized bibtex wasn't working, I've been trying only with pdflatex and bibtex to see if it's gonna work to then go back to Atom.

The pdf file is being created but without the cite, instead of it, it has a "[?]".
Thank you! I'm waiting for any response!

Comment: `I found no \bibstyle command-` means that there is no `\bibliographystyle` command in your document add `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

Comment: note `\centerline`, `\sc` and `\it` are all plain-tex style commands that should not be in a latex document (although they mostly work)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  in addition to what david says, you really don't need to specify `test.aux` to `bibtex`.  just `text` should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the bibliography style file. Before using the bibliography (.bib) file, i.e. references.bib in your case, you should include which style you are going to use.

There exists many bibliography styles including plain, ieee, ieeetr apalike, unsrt, ama, cj, nar etc. Moreover, before using this, you just need to add the .bst file in your current working directory.
Hope this fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Avoid using \it and \centerline. Use \textit{italic text} and \centering.